# Remove semicolons sequences of differing length with Regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Given some data:

```
test <- data.frame(strings = c('a;b;c;;;;;;;', 'd;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m', 'n;o;p;q;r;;;;;', ';;;;;;;;;' ))
```

How do I remove all trailing semicolons to get:

```
test <- data.frame(strings = c('a;b;c', 'd;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m', 'n;o;p;q;r', '' ))
```

Features of this dataframe:

1. maximum of 9 semicolons per row, separating a maximum of 10 characters
2. rows contain differing amounts of characters, and the semicolons always add to 9
3. when a row contains no characters, it contains 9 semicolons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the regex you want, in words, is "one or more semicolons followed by end of line". So this works:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  mutate(newstrings = gsub(";{1,}$", "", strings))

              strings          newstrings
1        a;b;c;;;;;;;               a;b;c
2 d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m
3      n;o;p;q;r;;;;;           n;o;p;q;r
4           ;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: add in where `mutate` comes from for those not familiar

Comment: Or just keep it to `gsub(";+$",  "", test$strings)` to be completely uncomplicated

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex, to select all sequence of 1 or more semicolons at the end of your string and replace it by '' in order to trim them.

```
;+$
```

Comment: Yes, I like `;+` better than my initial hurried effort :)